# Django Forms field_classes not working?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

Basically, what I am trying to comprehend is why the `field_classes` meta-property is not being used when trying to use my ModelForms.

The property field_classes was released in the Django version 1.9 (I am using 1.9.9) and there is not quite a lot of [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) about it.

According to the documentation, the following example should replace the `TypedChoiceField` generated for "action" for a `MultipleChoiceField`, but it doesn't take the `field_classes` property into account, ever.

```
# MODEL
class Starter(models.Model):
    action_choices = (
        ('elec', _('Electrical')),
        ('mec', _('Mechanical')),
        # Add many more
    )
    action = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        choices=action_choices,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

# FORM
class StarterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Starter
        fields = '__all__' # I also tried with ('action',)
        field_classes = {
            'action': forms.MultipleChoiceField,
        }
```

The reason behind this question is that I need to "repeat" this operation for 50+ models (yeah, I know) and I am trying to apply a DRY approach so I don't have to rewrite some of the things the ModelForm sets automatically from the Model (like defaults, required, choices, etc).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other DRY approach? Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: try if [TypedMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#typedmultiplechoicefield) works instead

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues sorry, I didn't see your comment. I tried it, but still no changes. Actually, when I generate a `StarterForm` instance and print its fields, action continues being a `TypedChoiceField`

Comment: Instead of `field_classes` if you explicitly set the `widget` for it, does it change?

Comment: If I modify the `widget` dict to use `SelectMultiple` for the `action` field I am able to see the change when rendering the form but, when I try to save it, django executes the `TypedChoiceField` validations over the `SelectMultiple` widget and raises an error. :/
@ResleyRodrigues

Comment: Okay my conclusion is that Django will not allow you to use a `MultipleChoiceField` for a model field that can store only a single value. If you were using an `ArrayField` you can set `field_classes` to `TypedMultipleChoice‌​Field` and `MultipleChoice‌​Field` is the default.

Comment: you can show how to use StarterForm ?